# How to log Error Message Contents in Rebus?

Tags: rebus

Is there anyway to log message contents when an exception occurs?

I looked at various logging extensions but they are just logging CorrelationId. And message contents are not available.

There is a CurrentMessge property in MessageContext, but that is not available at the time logger writes the exception.

I tried to handle PoisonMessage Event, which allows me to log the message contents.

```
public static void OnPoisonMessage(IBus bus, ReceivedTransportMessage receivedTransportMessage, Rebus.Bus.PoisonMessageInfo poisonMessageInfo) {

var message =  new JsonMessageSerializer().Deserialize(receivedTransportMessage);
    Log.Error("{@messageType} failed {@message}", message.Messages[0].GetType(), message);
}
```

This works great, but now I have two errors in the log one coming from my handler and the other coming from logger.

I am wondering if there is a better way to handle this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to simply log the message contents as JSON, I think you've found the right way to do it - at least that's the way I would have done it.

I'm curious though as to what problem you're solving by logging the message contents - you are aware of the fact that the failing message will end up in an error queue where you can inspect it?

If you're using MSMQ, you can inspect JSON-serialized messages using [Rebus' Snoop-tool](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Snoop), which is a simple MSMQ inspector. It will also allow you to move the message back into the input queue where it failed ("return to source queue")

A good way to monitor your Rebus installation is to set up some kind of alerts when something arrives in an error queue, and then you can look at the message (which event includes the caught exceptions in a special header) and then resolve the situation from there.

Comment: When a message fails due to a bug in the code, it is very useful to see the contents of message along with error to understand the context. DevOps usually control the access to queue infrastructure.  It also reduces cognitive load of looking at multiple places to understand the problem.